# How do I get console to loop until the right input is entered in C?

Tags: c, input, while-loop

I have a program in C simulating an ATM interaction between a user and the program by accepting choices of input to then produce an output.

The user has to enter the value 1111, for the transaction to continue, if this isn't true, the program prints out an error and keeps requiring the user to type in the correct pin until the program reads in 1111.

I have tried using a while loop to keep requesting for the correct value, 1111, and until it is entered, the program keeps asking the user to enter the right pin.

```
void main() {

    int pin;

    printf("Please enter the default pin: ");

    while ( pin != 1111 ) 
    {
        printf("Invalid input ");
        printf("Please enter the default pin again: ");
        scanf("%d", &pin);

        if (pin == 1111) 
        {
            //The program continues
        }

    }     
}
```

Every time I type in the wrong pin, it asks for the pin one more time and then crashes with an error that the program had stopped working. I think I'm causing an infinite loop but I'm not so sure what's going on.

Comment: You initialize `pin` to a *good value*, then go straight to `while !good value` which will not loop at all. So either you did not post the correct code or you are not seeing any prompts for a pin.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` returns a result (the number of successfully read items). You should use that result. Read documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and of every function you are using. Also, add a `\n` at the end of every `printf` format control string (or call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)...)

Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want this :

```
void main()
{
  int pin ;

  printf("Please enter the default pin: ");
  scanf("%d", &pin);  

  while ( pin != 1111 ) 
  {
    printf("Invalid input\n");
    printf("Please enter the default pin again: ");
    scanf("%d", &pin);
  }

 printf("program continues...");  //The program continues
}
```

Sample execution

```
Please enter the default pin: 1234
Invalid input
Please enter the default pin again: 2222
Invalid input
Please enter the default pin again: 1111
program continues...
```

Comment: No, `scanf` should *always* be tested for its result!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch right, but I think at this stage we can ignore this.

Comment: No you can't, since you don't initialize `pin`. If `scanf` fails, `pin` remains uninitialized.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch you are right, but `scanf` is evil anyway. `fgets` would be a better choice here. And when I mentioned "at this stage" I meant the C knowledge of the OP.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I tried doing it this way, and I'm only asked for the correct pin one more time and then the program crashes the next time I type in another incorrect value.

Comment: @geek.x where does it crash ? And what's the exact message displayed after the crash. What exactly is your input ? It works here provided you don't type anything else than numbers. If you type letters etc. The program enters into an infinite loop, but that's a problem with `scanf` and that's not a crash.

Answer (score 1):

This checks to see if scanf successfully reads an integer. If it fails it will read one character and try again.
If scanf reads an integer, it is checked to see if it is the correct pin. If not, it re-prompts and scanfs again.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int pin = 0;
    int ch = 0;

    printf ( "Enter the default pin\n");
    while ( pin != 1111) {
        if ( scanf ( "%d", &pin) == 1) { // scanf read an int                                                             
            if ( pin == 1111) {
                break; // the correct pin                                                                                 
            }
            else {
                printf ( "Enter the default pin\n"); //reprompt                                                           
            }
        }
        else {
            while ( ( ch = getchar()) != '\n') { //scanf failed to read int. clear input and retry
                if ( ch == EOF) {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "problem getting input\n");
                    return 1;//if EOF exit
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to getchar() in the failed case before looping. Is there something stuck in the stream? Without it my program loops but doesn't scan again.

Comment: See that's what I thought so I tried doing `fflush(stdin)` instead of `getchar()`. Is there a specific reason that doesn't work?